# Installing Python 2.7 on centos without yum, gcc and no cd rom mounted

Tags: python, gcc, centos

I have a very specific requirement:

Please note the following things before answering:
- I don't have network connectivity on the target machine
- I don't have the gcc installed on the target machine
- I already have Python 2.4 installed on the target machine
- I don't have yum working on the target machine
- My Centos on the target machine is appliance blasted and has no cd rom mounted

The question is, is there is any way I can upgrade Python 2.4 to 2.7??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a USB port?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely best answer is if an RPM exists both for Python 2.7, and CentOS platform you want - it's pretty simple. Extract the files from the RPM, copy them over manually. You can do this on a remote machine by running:

```
mkdir CPIOTMP 
cd CPIOTMP
rpm2cpio rpmfile.rpm
rpm2cpio - < rpmfile.rpm
rpm2cpio rpmfile.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

However, take note - by bypassing the package system and forcing the installation of a package in it's 'raw' form will ultimately cause you headaches if you don't know what you're doing.

Another solution would be to cross-compile Python 2.7 on a different box, this can be accomplished by specifying build= host= target=
variables to the 'configure' script. This has it's own set of problems if the machines are running different library versions.